# How to "split" an attachment with Mutt ? (Message/partial)

Tags: shell-script, mutt

A few days ago I started to use the library MUTT (send email) in the command line.

I know how to "modify/create" headers with the command line "my_hdr", but I can't find a way to send a big file (I know there is a limit. But I saw some library that "split" the attachment with an id to recompose the original file).

My question is: How can I do that (if it's possible ofc) with Mutt? My goal is to create a script that's why I use the command line

Comment: Can you please add more details? What does that `my_hdr` do? What is your attachment? Is it a binary file? Text?

Comment: With "my_hdr" you can "create" your own header (email) like set the field from if you want. Well I don't really have an attachment, I mean it's just a test so you can use whatever you want. I use just text with a lot of lines, I zipped the file and I want to send it. My question is more about : it is possible to "split" the attachment and send several mails. Then re-create the original after that. I'm a beginner with mutt and I'm not sure if this lib can do it or not..

Comment: This is what I'm doing : mutt -e "my_hdr Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" -e "set content_type=message/multipart' -b "my_adress" -s "test Big file" -a "my test file"

Answer (score 0):

Mutt will not split files. In a script, you need to use another utility for that, such as `split` from the GNU Coreutils, then use Mutt to send each generated file. For instance, to split `your_file` into one-megabyte parts and send each part one by one to `destination_address` with Mutt:

```
split -b 1M your_file out.
for i in out.*
do
  echo "Part $i" | mutt -a $i -- -s "Part $i" destination_address
done
```

You don't need to use `my_hdr` to generate MIME related headers: Mutt will do that for you.

Then the recipient will just need to extract each attachment, and use `cat out.*` to concatenate them.

**Note:** Before the split, first make sure that there are no files with the chosen prefix (`out.` in my example) in the directory.